# distro-base tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Let's say I use Linux Mint, and I have a question that is not specific to mint, but is specific to Debian. should I tag it `linux-mint`, `ubuntu`, `debian`? or maybe `debian-base`? I'm thinking maybe we should have a tag for noting that it comes from a *base* distro or upstream distro even though we may not be using that distro. Any thoughts on the matter?

[this diagram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gldt1009.svg) allows us to determine base distro's.

Another example is, for the most part any Sabayon user asking a `portage` question would also apply to Gentoo.

Thoughts?

Comment: Nice diagram, but it took me a good 10 minutes to find arch..

Comment: @Stefan yeah, tbh I have an idea for most of them off the top of my head. however... you could use your browser search to find it ;) Arch is generally considered a -base distro IMO, I can't think of who their upstream would be.

Comment: My general rule of thumb would be... does this distro have an upstream distro and is it relevant to them as well.

Comment: image is out-of-date right? I mean, where is Arch Hurd?

Comment: @Stefan I couldn't say who updates it or how... so probably it's on wikipedia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a difference between a Sabayon user asking a Portage question and a Gentoo user asking a Portage question? If not I would just tag it `[portage] [gentoo]`. There doesn't seem to need to be a separate `[gentoo-base]` if the answers are going to be the same, it just fragments the tag.

It *is* important that the community retag questions that are tagged incorrectly, like `[sabayon] [portage]` if the question has nothing to do with `[sabayon]` specifically (I can see leaving `[sabayon]`, but it should almost certainly have `[gentoo]` as well), which is why the rep limit for retagging is so massively low

Comment: it depends... there may be a difference... sabayon has its own packages in some cases. I was just throwing out some examples. I suppose this is as much of a question do we tag with both sabayon and gentoo? or just tag based on what the user is using.

Comment: There will certainly be cases (like things that apply to debian) apply to 100 other distro's

Comment: I suppose one of my thoughts (fears?) is that people will watch the [ubuntu] tag when they could/should be watching [debian] do you think that will not be a problem?